# Resize a winform window only when resize end

Tags: c#, winforms, events, resize, window

Is there a way to resize a `Winform` window  just in **Resize End**?

This means that as long as the mouse is clicked I see lines and only when I leave the mouse (Resize end) window will resize on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use [DrawReversibleFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe.aspx). Default resizing will need to be disabled (FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle).

Basic Logic is -

`MouseDown` - Begin tracking 
`MouseMove` - Draw Reversible Frame
`MouseUp` - Stop Drawing Reversible Frame. Resize Form.

Luckily this MSDN [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/82688e76-a513-49d4-b8f1-b62ecae56a0b/winforms-how-can-i-show-only-the-borders-when-resizing-the-form-using) had working code for this. I have a made a working sample for you.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/427g2h2ajm5z62m/ResizeFrame.zip

You will need to tweak this so Form resize only happens when user 'MouseDown' near the border.

Answer (score 2):

If it's fine to only have the contained controls resize then (and the Form itself - immediately) - use the Form's [ResizeEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

<sup>(I'm assuming this is the case, because usually there is no reason to delay the Form's resize itself, rather the contained controls', because their resize might be 'expensive'.)</sup>

**Note**: "The ResizeEnd event is also generated after the user moves a form".

Comment: Thanks! Perfect for saving a program's size / location. It was bothering me that it happened every tick during the resizing/moving process. This solved the problem beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
protected override void OnResizeBegin(EventArgs e) {
            SuspendLayout();
            base.OnResizeBegin(e);
        }
        protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e) {
            ResumeLayout();
            base.OnResizeEnd(e);
        }
```